# Update a table more efficient when doing calculations on his updating fields

Tags: java, mysql, performance, calculated-field

I want to update a table with a given value X. The update concerns some calculations however. This is the query (in mysql):

```
INSERT INTO table_X (
  id,
  type,
  count,
  last,
  sum,
  ssq,
  date
) VALUES (
  #{id},
  #{type},
  1,
  #{X},
  #{X},
  #{X} * #{X},
  now()
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  count = count+1,
  last= #{X},
  sum = sum + #{X},
  ssq = ssq + #{X} * #{X},
  date = now()
```

The query is called from a Java context. It takes about 16-18 seconds to execute it 100000 times on varying id's.

Now when I run the query but use fixed variables instead of fetching the old ones and calculate with them (e.g. `ssq = ssq + #{X} * #{X}` -> `ssq = 5`), it only takes 8 seconds! Which is a major improvement.

It gave me the idea to do the calculations in Java. To do that, I (think I) need to Select the record with id `#{id}` first, do the calculations and then Update the table. But because I now need to access the table twice the time needed grew to over 30 seconds.

Does anyone have an idea if there are better ways to update the table with calculations on its own fields?

Comment: The `UPDATE` which was occurring after the `INSERT` was taking place within a single (atomic) transaction in your MySQL database.  To do the equivalent in Java, you would also need to do everything within a transaction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know the concept of atomic transactions, but how can/should I implement that in Java?

Comment: In real life, will you be doing 10K updates all at once?  Or will they gradually come in over the hours/days?

Comment: Gradually come in, normally maybe a few dozen a day.

Answer (score 0):

You must make 2 Changes:
1. change #{X} to VALUES(fieldname) like VALUES(sum)
2. put more ROWS (1000 or more) in one INSERT Statement

```
INSERT INTO table_X (
  id, type, count, last,
  sum, ssq, date
) VALUES 
( -- Values for ROW 1
  #{id},  #{type}, 1,
  #{X},  #{X}, #{X} * #{X},
  now()
),
( -- Values for ROW 2
  #{id},  #{type}, 1,
  #{X},  #{X}, #{X} * #{X},
  now()
),
( -- Values for ROW 3
  #{id},  #{type}, 1,
  #{X},  #{X}, #{X} * #{X},
  now()
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  count = count+1,
  last= VALUES(last),
  sum = sum + VALUES(sum),
  ssq = ssq + VALUES(ssq) * VALUES(ssq),
  date = now();
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. id is unique, so I don't see how adding 3 duplicate values would make sense?
Also, #{X} comes from Java (the query is defined in an .xml-file), so shouldn't it be like sum = VALUES(sum) + #{X}?

Comment: i cant say how you can produce the 3 ROW of Values in your application, but you CAN use VALUE(fieldname) . This is everytime the Argument from the ROW

Comment: INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b); you can find it here : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/

Comment: I can't use values, it stores the initial value then and retrieves it. It sure is faster, but every record is only created and then updated according to the initial value every time the id passes again. So if I insert a record with nonexisting id = 5 100 times, it will  be created and updated once (count is 2 where it should be 100).

Comment: can you post one query please

Comment: Certainly. so I execute the next statement three times:
    `mysql> INSERT INTO delivery_statistics VALUES ( 1500000, 'share', 1, 5, 5, 5*5, now() ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = VALUES(count) + 1, last = 5, sum = VALUES(sum) + 5, ssq = VALUES(ssq) + 5*5, date = now();`

This produces the following, but count should be 3, sum 15 and ssq 75. 

`+------------+-------+-------+------+-----+-----+---------------------+
| booking_id | type  | count | last | sum | ssq | date                |

|    1500000 | share |     2 |    5 |  10 |  50 | 2016-01-05 12:03:29 |`

Comment: do you men this ?? 
INSERT INTO delivery_statistics 
VALUES
  ( 1500000, 'share', 1, 5, 5, 5*5, now() ) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  count = count + VALUES(count) ,
  last = 5, 
  sum = sum + VALUES(sum),
  ssq = ssq + VALUES(ssq) ,
  date = now();

Comment: No It doesn't. It should keep track of how many times the record is updated, but with the use of VALUE(...), it uses the values of the INSERT INTO-part instead of the actual value stored in the table.

Comment: INSERT INTO delivery_statistics 
VALUES
  ( 1500000, 'share', 1, 5, 5, 5*5, now() ) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  count = count + 1 ,
  last = 5, 
  sum = sum + VALUES(sum),
  ssq = ssq + VALUES(ssq) ,
  date = now();  Then increment only the count on update

Comment: Yes, this works correctly, but alas, it doesn't provide a performance improvement.

Comment: now you must put more rows in one insert.
NSERT INTO delivery_statistics VALUES ( 1500000, 'share', 1, 5, 5, 5*5, now() ),( 1500001, 'xxxxx', 1, 5, 5, 5*5, now() ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1 , last = 5, sum = sum + VALUES(sum), ssq = ssq + VALUES(ssq) , date = now();

Comment: ok, but what if in practice these updates are at random, any moment of the day?

Comment: you wrote "The query is called from a Java context. It takes about 16-18 seconds to execute it 100000 times on varying id's." so you can spit the 100000 in pieces of 1000 or so

Comment: Yes, my mistake. The numbers are for testing, in reality it can be called thorough the day.

Comment: this wars only to reduce the calls to the INSERT Function, so you only can optimize you mysql server to get faster